# Wireless laser mouse dead-zone issue

Tags: mouse

For months, if not closer to a year now, I've had an ongoing issue with my Logitech MX620 mouse wherein it will occasionally hit a spot where it just cuts out a bit over a small dead-zone.

Here are the trouble-shooting attempts I've made thus far

- Changing surfaces
- Disabling other wireless signals
- Swapping receiver USB ports
- Moving the entire computer
- Changing light exposure
- Wearing different clothing
- Testing in multiple operating systems
- Having the mouse and receiver
  replaced

What really makes it problematic is that it's not persistent.  There seems to be, as far as I've been able to discern, no singular cause that I can repeat, and thusly little way to immediately test a result.

The only things left that I can think of are the highly unlikely ones that I'd typically assume just to be zero possibility, such as both mice/receivers being faulty, or multiple USB ports or cross-OS drivers being problematic.

Any ideas very appreciated, because I've gone about as far as I can on this one.

I run both Linux (Xubuntu) and Windows (XP), so I can use tools from either for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your hardware is okay (you swapped mice/receiver/usb ports) and assuming your mouse surface is okay (you said you change ?mats?) then intermittent jamming may be an issue.  Try using a USB extension cable and mounting the receiver directly under your desk under the mouse surface.  Wireless mice use 2.4G as does WiFi as do microwave ovens, cordless phones, walkie talkies, as may the military when they spin up some of their high power radios.  Putting the receiver at point blank range may help.

Comment: I've tried this kind of thing a few different ways (less than perfectly), but for whatever reason I hadn't thought of an extension cord.  I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Yeah, I have a Mcrosoft 6000 keyboard - the keyboard looses sync all the time unless you almost glue the receiver under it.

Comment: ...which is why I prefer wired ones, mostly.